# How can I use a $broadcast start / stop event to toggle a field between true and false?

Tags: angularjs

I have two events:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('cfpLoadingBar:started');
$rootScope.$broadcast('cfpLoadingBar:completed');
```

How can I "in my controller" use these events to toggle on and off the state of a property called "loading" ?

Comment: you can use `$on` to listen to the broadcast event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to that event using `$on`

```
$scope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:started', function(event, data) {
    // turn on that value
});
```

Similarly,

```
 $scope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:completed', function(event, data) {
        // turn off the value
    });
```

DEMO:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
     $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('cfpLoadingBar:started');
     }, 1000);
     $timeout(function() {
         $rootScope.$broadcast('cfpLoadingBar:completed');
     }, 3000);

   $scope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:started', function(event, data) {
          $scope.flag = "on";
   });
   
   $scope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:completed', function(event, data) {
     $scope.flag = "off";
   });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h1>Flag :  {{flag}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```